# Extract object keys within the function

Tags: typescript

Its pretty often than we need type that is union of keys of given object.
Solution is simple :

```
const myObject = { 
  "key" : "value", 
  "anotherKey" : "anotherValue" 
}

type keysOfMyObject = keyof typeof myObject;
```

and voila `keysOfMyObject` is `"key" | "anotherKey"`.

Great but now lets try to provide type of myObject.

```
const myObject : Record<string,string> = { 
  "key" : "value", 
  "anotherKey" : "anotherValue" 
}

type keysOfMyObject = keyof typeof myObject;
```

ooops `keysOfMyObject` is now `string`.
It this case we could restrict type of `myObject` to be `Record<'key' | 'anotherKey'>` but what if object is argument of function and can have potentially any string as a key ?
I mean

```
const myFunction = function(dictionary : Record<string,string> ) {
  return function acceptOnlyKeysFromDictionaty(key : keyof typeof dictionary){
    console.log("key", key); 
  }
};
```

Do one know how to make function `acceptOnlyKeysFromDictionary` properly typed so it only accepts keys from `dictionary` as a keys ? Above it accepts any string so `myFunction({"allowedKey" : "value"})("illegalKey")` is still ok for typescript.

Comment: With typescript 4.9 there is the `satisfies` keyword, which is a partial solution to your case

Comment: The carried function case can be solved with constrained type parameter in the outer function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

explanation of @parzh .'s answer

```
const myFunction = function <D extends Record<string, string>>(dictionary: D) {
  return function acceptOnlyKeysFromDictionaty(key: keyof typeof dictionary) {
    console.log("key", key);
  }
};
```

Demo: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAYw9gdgzgLgBAWwJ4DECuEQwJaTgXjgDMMtcI4AeAETgFMAPGOiAEyjgCU7wAnVyrF7YIAcwA0cISNEA+WQApW2MpACGvJAC441AJRwA3sDhxedGGl4USmHHjUgQdAA4wA8hAA2SANJ0kKBReMARqFXsINRgkBQBrAJ0EpDAiOBiXOlS4ZVUozQNjU1NwaDAvOgA6LzBRBQAiZPrJZL0AbhM4AF9gLra4YFBIWDhHZzcCRFRSSIUiuHqYKHqdAHIRVkZV3r1BsdcYBqX63f23BoArZb0gA